# What do assembly registers refer to in C code?

Tags: c, assembly

I'm currently refactoring c code and inside there is assembly code:

```
asm("movl $8, %esi\n\t"
    movl $.LC0, %edi\n\t"
    "movl $0, %eax");
```

What doe each of the registers mean? In the c code, there isn't other asm code that assigns $8 or $.LC0, I'm assuming $0 is just a zero value

Comment: It means that this C code is targetting a specific CPU, and each one of those registers means exactly that: that specific CPU reguster.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik is there anyway to know what exactly are those register values, not sure the code is moving these values

Comment: It loads certain values in to registers, and has no other direct effect than that. It's also horribly broken code written by someone who didn't know what they were doing.

Comment: If you saw this C code: "esi = 8; edi = &_LC0; eax = 0;` then is there any way to know what exactly are those variable values?

Answer (score 3):

At the assembly level, `.LC0` is a label, and one that you should only find in compiler output, not in hand-written assembly.

Labels that start with `.LC` are generated by gcc to mark the location of string literals. The most likely meaning of `movl $.LC0, %edi` is that `%edi` will point to the first string literal that the compiler encountered in the source file. But that's obviously not a clean thing to want to do.

If you're trying to reverse  engineer some malicious code, you'll probably have to show the whole thing for it to make any sense. The global interaction between the C and the assembly points to some attempt at obfuscation.

If you weren't trying to reverse engineer some malicious code... start considering this code malicious now.

Answer (score 1):

They refer to nothing; this inline asm fragment is garbage, and will only do anything useful if exactly the right surrounding code is compiled with exactly the right version of the right compiler with the right optimization options, so that the compiler-generated code around it works the way that fragment expects.

See the [inline-assembly](/questions/tagged/inline-assembly) tag wiki for links to tutorials and docs that explain how to write GNU C inline asm code that doesn't suck.

This code isn't just technically "unsafe", it really will break with the slightest change to the surrounding code or optimization options, because it doesn't tell the compiler anything about what C values it thinks its modifying.

The only things with any known meaning in the code fragment are the immediate constants 0 and 8.  In AT&T syntax, immediates are prefixed with `$`.  (`mov .LC0, %edi` (without the $) would be a load from that address, instead of putting the address into the register.  But you don't know which constant the compiler decided to label with `.LC0`, or what the compiler is going to do with `%edi`, so this is useless)  See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to x86 docs, and assembler manuals.

See the asm for Hello World in C on [the Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g62,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-Wextra++-O3',source:'%23include%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++printf(%22Hello+World%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3), for an example of compiler-generated code.